# Is the .exe file format copyrighted by Microsoft in a creative naming capacity?

Tags: copyright, licensing, music

I wanted to know if the name of the .exe file format used by Microsoft Operating Systems is copyrighted. As in, is it possible that I'm committing copyright infringement by adding that suffix (".exe") onto the end of the name of a creative work such as a song with intent to make it sound computer-related/technology-related and that I could technically be at legal risk from Microsoft?

For clarification, the file would still be an audio file, just with a file name such as "aaaaa.exe". Technically, it's possible that the full audio file would be "aaaaa.exe.wav".

If I am at risk, what would remedy this? Removing said content?

Thank you.

Comment: You're fine with using .exe.  ("File extensions are functional, and functional uses cannot be trademarked.")  Might not be the best choice, though, because of filename issues.  Maybe aaadotexe instead?